# Using extern to refer to a function defined in a different compilation unit

Tags: c++, extern

Due to some static data, I have a function

`void foo(MyNamespace::bar)`

defined in a certain compilation unit. But its point of use is in another compilation unit. So I use

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    extern void foo(bar);
}
```

But the linker can't find the function definition. Am I misusing `extern`?

Comment: Is `foo` defined inside `MyNamespace`?

Comment: Your use of extern is fine.  It looks like the linker is missing the compilation unit containing the definition of the function, or the definition is in the wrong namespace, or similar.  What linker are you using?

Comment: It would be better to define the function outside its namespace, with the qualified name, `void MyNamespace::foo(bar) {...}`. Then you'll get an error, rather than an unexpected new declaration, if the arguments don't match the `extern` declaration.

Comment: You could remove that `extern` and it would have no effect whatsoever - the problem is your (mis)use of namespaces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`extern` *can* be used for this kind of thing.

Your problem is that the linker is expecting a function `MyNamespace::foo(bar);` due to the fact that your `extern` statement is within `MyNamespace`.

You have two choices:

1. use `extern void foo(MyNamespace::bar);` at your "point of use". Don't enclose that line within `MyNamespace`.
2. Alternatively, enclose the function definition within `MyNamespace`.